# Decidability of bi-cartesian closed categories

Tags: lambda-calculus, category-theory, type-theory

Is the decision problem for the free bi-cartesian closed category (BCCC) decidable?  Equivalently, is equality decidable for the simply-typed lambda calculus extended with strong n-ary products and sums?  The decision problem for the free *almost* BCCC is decidable:

http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~txa/publ/lics01.pdf

But this work does not include an initial object, or empty type in lambda-calulus terms, although they speculate their method can extend to BCCCs.

Answer (score 0):

I will give a partial answer that will help illustrate why the initial object is being excluded. Things start to collapse when initial objects are combined with exponentials; or terminal objects with co-exponentials. This collapse becomes complete when both exponentials and co-exponentials are present; in which case, the decideability problem becomes trivial, reducing to provability in a logic, while the "normal form" reduction problem becomes more difficult - ironically.

I've posted more details here. I can't answer it here, because the "Improperly formatted code" false positive bug in StackOverflow makes its interface broken beyond repair. (I get it even for an empty display window and there's no computer programming in my answer, since this isn't even a computer question!)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032422/decidability-of-bi-cartesian-closed-categories

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Since I asked it, I believe that Gabriel Scherer gave an affirmative answer to this question in his paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01213

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.